# Questions on JavaScript's Call function?

Tags: javascript

I read a snippet here

```
var obj = {
    birth: 1990,
    getAge: function (year) {
        var b = this.birth; // 1990
        var fn = (y) => y - this.birth; // this.birth is still 1990
        return fn.call({birth:2000}, year);
    }
};
obj.getAge(2015); // 25
```

Why `birth` attribute is not changed, since `{birth: 2000}` has been plugged in.

Comment: That's an arrow function. `this` in arrow functions always refers the `this` outside of it.

Comment: var fn = (y) => y - this.birth; // this.birth is still 1990
        return fn.call({birth:2000}, year); WHY????

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions ( => ) dont have their own context (this);

So you  either need a normal function:

```
var obj = {
birth: 1990,
getAge: function (year) {
    var b = this.birth; // 1990
    var fn = function(y){ return  y - this.birth; }// this.birth is still 2000
    return fn.call({birth:2000}, year);
}
};
obj.getAge(2015); // 25
```

Or you leave away this unnecessary function and simply do:

```
getAge:function(year){
 return year-this.birth>=0?year-this.birth:(console.error("not born yet"),0);
}
```